# Term for menu that appears at the top of many webpages

Tags: menu, terminology

What is the term for the menu that appears at the top right of many webpages? Here are two examples:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe: Header, Topbar, Navbar, Topmenu

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not entirely sure if there is any specific name for it. It could be referred to as a "Fixed Menu" or a "Navigation Menu".

As far as a name based on its position. It really depends. To me I would say its a Fixed Navigation Menu because it retains its location between pages and does offer navigation. It is not on the side of the webpage, so it would not be a Side Menu, and its not on the footer, so its not a Footer Navigation Menu.